# Need help installing FinchTv from a package

Tags: software-installation

I need to install FinchTv for a school. I've downloaded the `tar.gz` and extracted it. There doesn't seem to be an install readme. I've attempted to run `/.configure`, `make`, and `install`, on a executable in the file called `finchtv, but nothing happens.

In the notes it reads, "Note:

```
FinchTV on Solaris requires libCstd.so.1.  
All Solaris 8 installs include this library except for the minimum installation cluster.
The 108434 and 108435 patches will install libCstd.so.1 if SUNWlibC is 
installed."
```

On the requirments it states it has been tested on, **RedHat: v. 9, Enterprise WS release 3 / SuSE Linux: v. 8.2**

So what's the deal? Do I need to download some library or something before I can install it? I'm new to Ubuntu so any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On 14.04 (64 bits) it works out of the box, nothing to build really.

Just extract the following [archive](http://www.geospiza.com/finchtv/download/programs/linux/finchtv_1_3_1.tar.gz), open a terminal and type `./finchtv`

[image]

Comment: I'm am also running 14.04 (64 bit). When I run './finchtv' it reads 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. Why would I be getting this error? Thank you.

Comment: @Linux_dog_poop Let me try in a clean virtual machine, I may have a dependency installed that is missing in a base installation.

Comment: @Linux_dog_poop Tested in a clean 14.04.1 x64 VM, it works flawlessly. Are you sure of running the same release/arch?

Comment: @Linux_dog_poop: `uname -a` should return something like `Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: it returns `3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`